# Conic sections in standard form

Tags: conic-sections

I'm trying to convert the equation

$$x^2 +2y^2 +4x-4y+4=0$$

into its standard form by choosing a new set of axes.

Yet, when I go down the conventional route, there is no **xy** term so $$cot2{\theta}={(a-c)/{b}}$$ doesn't work.

I've simplified it but it turns out as 
$$(x+2)^2 +2(y-1)^2 =1$$

So, it is a circle in standard form already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$(x+2)^2+2(y-1)^2=1$$
is not correct and that it is not a circle.

We have
$$x^2 +2y^2 +4x-4y+4=0$$
$$\iff (x^2+4x+4)+2(y^2-2y+1)-2=0$$
$$\iff (x+2)^2+2(y-1)^2=2$$
$$\iff \frac{(x+2)^2}{\left(\sqrt 2\right)^2}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{1^2}=1$$
which is an ellipse.

Comment: Thanks. It was a slip with completing the squares. The only thing I'm confused about is why I was told to choose a ''new coordinates''? Given that it's in its standard form already.

Comment: @Yankee: You are welcome. Well, ask the person if you can:)

Comment: @Yankee I think they are referring to the coordinates $x^{\prime}=x+2, y^{\prime}=y-1$.